# Is UDP/TCP network communications supported in Gluon Mobile?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I couldn't find anything in the documentation for Gluon-Mobile or on StackOverflow.

But, does Gluon Mobile allow me to do custom UDP/TCP network communications?

I have a standard desktop JavaFX application that uses UDP/TCP to talk to some devices on our network and I was thinking it would be cool if I could write a mobile app to communicate with our devices.

I'm just not sure if the low level network communication is supported.

Note, I'm not talking about "Gluon Connect", our apps talk to our hardware devices locally and no cloud is needed.

Thanks..

Comment: Gluon Connect is not related to the cloud, it's a library that allows you to make REST and file requests in a way that makes them more compatible with JavaFX than a regular request. Last I've seen, the REST requests are build on the old `HttpURLConnection`. Gluon Cloud Link is the cloud storage service. Gluon does not offer any out-of-the-box UDP solution, but you should be able to write one of your own.